# Update table column using table in another SQL Server database while using a spatial function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial

I would like to update a table column using a spatial function with another database table.  This is what I've come up with....

```
UPDATE FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs
SET county = t2.CountyName
FROM OtherDatabase.dbo.tblCounty AS t2

WHERE t2.cty_geog.STIntersects(
GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('Point(' + FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs.lng + ' ' +
FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs.lat + ')', 26915)
)
```

but I get this error...
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. This is one of those silly things in TSQL. You need a `= 1`.

*That's the answer to your question, but I would also be tempted to use [`POINT(lat, lon, SRID)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx) to address your comment.*

```
UPDATE FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs
SET county = t2.CountyName
FROM OtherDatabase.dbo.tblCounty AS t2
WHERE t2.cty_geog.STIntersects(geography::Point(FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs.lat,
                                                FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs.lng,
                                                26915)) = 1
```

---

In a language like C#, you could write something like:

```
bool val = true;

if (val)
    // do stuff
```

But in TSQL, you have to write the equivalent to:

```
bool val = true;

if (val == true)
    // do stuff
```

This isn't specific to SQL Spatial, of course, you'd also have to specify `WHERE bitColumnName = 1` or, as your example illustrates, `WHERE bitReturningFunction(args) = 1`.

Comment: Ah, yes I overlooked that = 1.  Thanks Matthew!  I ran into a couple more issues - was using incorrect SRID and needed to Cast my lat/lngs as varchar....                                          UPDATE FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs
SET county = t2.CountyName
FROM OtherDatabase.dbo.tblCounty AS t2
WHERE t2.cty_geog.STIntersects(
GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('Point(' + CAST(FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs.lng AS VARCHAR) + ' ' +
CAST FirstDatabase.dbo.track_logs.lat AS VARCHAR) + ')', 4269)
)

Comment: @razor_nate You could use the `Point` function to address the casting matter, I've updated my answer.